# Getting MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey of MPMoviePlayerController nil

Tags: ios, swift3

I have use MPMoviePlayerController in my app. I am trying to get Done button event of MPMoviePlayerController. But I am getting nil value in  [MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] and because of it app is crashing. This is my code:

```
// Define notification in class
let notificationName = Notification.Name("moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked")

//---register and  posted notification in viewDidLoad()    

// Register to receive notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PlayVideo.moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked), name: self.notificationName, object: nil)

// Post notification
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.notificationName, object: nil)

//invoking player
playVideo()


//Event for moviePlayer Done Button Pressed (method for notification) 
func moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked(note: NSNotification) {       
    print ("delegate called....")

    let reason = note.userInfo?[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey]
    if (MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: reason as! Int) == MPMovieFinishReason.userExited) {

        print ("Done button clicked.")
        self.delegate.exitVideoPlayer()
    }
}

//—code for 
func playVideo() {
    //--Adjust height and width of player as per device
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    print ("self.attachmentURL : \(self.attachmentURL)")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let url:URL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
        self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        self.moviePlayer!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.width, height: self.height);
        self.videoContainerView.addSubview(self.moviePlayer!.view)
        self.moviePlayer!.isFullscreen = false
        self.moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.embedded

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }

}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Stop listening notification
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil);
}
```

Comment: you do know that [`MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey` is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerplaybackdidfinishreasonuserinfokey), along with MPMoviePlayerController right?

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem now.  You're posting a "`moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked`" notification with no object and no `userInfo` dictionary.

Why are you doing it this way?  The user is the one who clicks the "done" button and then iOS / movie player creates the "done" notification for your app to handle.

**Remove** the `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.notificationName, ...` line up there.

And change your code to this:

```
//Event for moviePlayer Done Button Pressed (method for notification) 
func moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked(notification: NSNotification) {       
    print ("delegate called....")

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    {
        let finishReason = MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: (notification.userInfo[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).intValue)
        if (finishReason == MPMovieFinishReason.userExited) 
        {
            print ("Done button clicked.")
            self.delegate.exitVideoPlayer()
        }
    } else {
        print("I shouldn't be manually posting a moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked notification without a userInfo dictionary")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting finishReason nil.  App is crashing on  this line  let finishReason = MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: (notification.userInfo![MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).intValue)

Comment: I had a typo in there - `notification` should be `note`.  Is it still crashing?

Comment: ..Yeah I corrected , it is still crashing. Is the code written by me for register and post notification  right?

Comment: I see the lines where you register and post a notification, but which function do they live in?  (e.g. `viewDidLoad`??)

Comment: I have written  register and post a notification code in viewDidLoad and then calling playVideo() method.